# Straight image in rotated container

Tags: css, nuxt.js

I am trying to create a visual for my project where the image is placed in a rotated container (div), however when the container is rotated the image inside gets rotated to the same number of degrees as the container.

Does anyone know how can I have the image straight and covering the container while the container is rotated?

```
<template>
  <div class="p-4">
    <div class="w-80 h-80 bg-blue-500 rotate-90">
      <div class="w-80 h-80 bg-red-500 rotate-45">
        <img
          class="h-full w-full object-cover object-center"
          src="https://www.aerointernational.de/content/uploads/2022/09/albums-global-8000-exterior-1_0-scaled-1150x600.jpg"
          fit="fill"
          alt="aircraft"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Please see image codesandbox to for a clearer depiction of the issue.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hardcore-microservice-vix2uh?file=/pages/index.vue

I am using Nuxt / Tailwind CSS.

Comment: Something like this? https://play.tailwindcss.com/Nbi2imbhAU

Comment: Please note that the [<img>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-img-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: @kissu, hmm not really. I want the image to be straight while in a rotated container. 
Please have a look at the below, I want the shape of the image to be exactly the shape of the red square, but when you look at it not to be rotated as the red square is.

https://play.tailwindcss.com/y07m3Bvhku

Here is what I try to achieve:
https://freeimage.host/i/HJeF7nV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one is using clip path: https://play.tailwindcss.com/vPFMKkR9WS

Otherwise, you can also do something like this: https://play.tailwindcss.com/Mume9LHfhm

```html
<div class="m-20">
  <section class="relative pt-20 pl-8">
    <div class="absolute h-64 w-64 rotate-45 rounded-3xl bg-blue-500"></div>
    <img class="absolute h-64 w-64 -rotate-[38deg] rounded-3xl object-cover object-center" src="http://i.imgur.com/kreZqnx.jpg" fit="fill" alt="aircraft" />
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate providing two solutions :)